# Available dnsmasq from vm in host system

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, virtualization

My Ubuntu server with installed Dnsmasq is running inside Hyper-V in Windows 10 host and ip address of server with dnsmasq is `10.10.0.1`.
In Hyper-V are running more Ubuntu servers (Landscape, Aptly, ...) and dns namespaces are resolved correctly in private network (all vms are connected in private network by `eht1` interface), but I'm not able to resolve VMs from Windows host by domain name. Here is `/etc/hosts` at VM with dnsmasq:

```
127.0.0.1    dns
10.10.0.1    dns
10.10.0.2    landscape
10.10.0.3    aptly
```

And dnsmasq configuration `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
no-dhcp-interface=eth0
no-dhcp-interface=eth1
```

What am I missing? How to configure dnsmasq or windows to resolve vms by domain names?
Here is screenshot with configuration of LAN adapter for private network in hyper-v.

[image]

Comment: hv u tried editing /etc/resolv.conf and hosts file on windows??

Comment: Sure, I can edit hosts file in Windows and manually added ips and names, but thit is what dns do, this is a reason, why I'm using dnsmasq.